# How to pass a parameter through another bean's object inside a method called from <f:event listener="...">

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

How to pass a parameter through another bean's object inside a method called from `<f:event listener="...">`?

I am trying to pass a parameter generated by another bean inside a `showData()` method that is to be called on using

```
<f:event listener="#{myTransformerBeans.showData}">
```

The parameter would be `#{myDataBean.myId}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could also try

```
<f:event listener="#{myTransformerBeans.showData(myDataBean.myId)}">
```