# Pass a parameter inside <f:event listener="#{myBean.retrieveData(#{})">

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I need to populate one datatable using database dynamically in which i need to call a retieveData() method and pass a id to criteria my result inside the method. The parameter that is to be passed is coming from another bean by #{anotherBean.id}. My question is how to pass this parameter inside the method...?
Following is what i am trying to do...

```
<f:metadata>
     <f:event listener="#{myBean.retrieveData(#{anotherBean.id)}" type="preRenderComponent" id="fevent"/>
</f:metadata>
```

Comment: There is a solultion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013343/how-to-pass-a-parameter-through-another-beans-object-inside-a-method-called-fro/10013560#10013560

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass it through attribute.

Here is what I do on JSF:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event listener="#{myBean.retrieveData}" type="preRenderView" id="fevent"/>
    <f:attribute name="myid" value="#{anotherBean.id)" />
</f:metadata>
```

Meanwhile the managed bean (myBean) is as follow:

```
public void retrieveData(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
    String id = (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("myid");
}
```

Make sure not to use '()' when calling the managed bean's method on listener of f:event tag.

Answer (score 3):

Basically

```
<f:metadata>
     <f:event listener="#{myBean.retrieveData(anotherBean.id)}" type="preRenderComponent" id="fevent"/>
</f:metadata>
```

should do. But why don't you inject `anotherBean` into `myBean` and retrieve id in your Java code? It is usually better to keep this kind of logic in your Java code rather than view - xhtml file in this case.